# Is there anyway to connect and edit MySql in VSC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I'm completely new to this database stuff and I have looked everywhere for the answer to this question.

I'm trying to practice MySql and thought it would be cool if I could connect my database to VSC and use it with CSS to style and add Jquery/JS to my tables.

I have looked everywhere, but can only figure out how to make queries with the help from MySql plugin, is there anyway to connect it to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Andreas! Querying MySQL requires a server, and is not possible from HTML/JS alone.

Typically, a web application is comprised of a client application using HTML/CSS and Javascript that calls API endpoints provided by a back-end server (you may be most comfortable [learning NodeJS with Express](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial)).

Querying MySQL from Node is done using an npm package such as [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

As you continue your learning journey, please try to be very specific regarding what aspect of the technology stack you are addressing. The more specific your question, the better your answers will be.